# Without PowerMock Need to Initialize static final class

Tags: java, spring, junit, mockito

Hi I am writing a Junit test case for a Util class file.  My code coverage is not covering after the try block. I can understand static block and static final variables configurator and restEndPoint is not initialized.  I know we can use powermockito but i need to achieve only with Mockito. Sharing the Util file and the test case which i have written.

```
public class JsonUtil {

    private static Properties properties;

    private static ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    private static String response;

    private static Config config;

    private static String path;

    private static String baseLocation;

    private static final String fileSeperator = "/";

    private static final RestEndPoint restEndPoint = new RestEndPoint();

    private static ServiceBase serviceBase;

    private static String suffix;

    private static final Configurator configurator = Configurator.getInstance();

    static transient final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getInstance().getLogger(JsonUtil.class);

    static {
        baseLocation = configurator.get("config.server.backup.basepath");
        suffix = configurator.get("config.server.backup.suffix.filename");
        restEndPoint.setBaseUrl(configurator.get("config.server.base.url"));
        restEndPoint.setApplicationName(configurator.get("config.server.application-name"));
        restEndPoint.setEnvironment(configurator.get("config.server.environment"));
        restEndPoint.setUserName(configurator.get("config.server.username"));
        restEndPoint.setPValue(System.getenv("config.server.password"));
        logger.info("Rest EndPoint for config server has been configured");
        objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    }

    public static void getInstance(String prefix) throws Exception {
        createConfigurator(prefix);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private static void createConfigurator(String prefix) throws Exception {
        AsyncSecret[] values = AsyncSecret.values();
        Path fullPath = Paths.get(baseLocation + fileSeperator + prefix + fileSeperator + suffix);
        path = fullPath.normalize().toString();
        File file = new File(path);
        try {
            serviceBase = new ServiceBase(restEndPoint);
            response = processRequest(serviceBase);
            if (response != null) {
                config = objectMapper.readValue(response, Config.class);
                for (PropertySource propertySource : config.getPropertySources()) {
                    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entries : propertySource.getSource().entrySet()) {
                        for (AsyncSecret val : values) {
                            if (entries.getKey().equals(val.vaultKey)) {
                                configurator.getAll().put(val.originalKey, entries.getValue());
                                properties.setProperty(val.originalKey, entries.getValue());
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                savePropertiesToFile(file);
            }
        } catch (IOException | InterruptedException | ExecutionException | KeyManagementException
                | NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            handleConfiguratorException(file, values, e);
        }
    }

    private static void savePropertiesToFile(File file) throws IOException {
        if (!file.exists()) {
        File parentFile = file.getParentFile();
        if (!parentFile.exists() && parentFile.mkdirs()) {
            log.info("Backup file location directory created");
        }
    }
    try (FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file)) {
        properties.store(outputStream, "Updated the configuration");
    }
    }

    private static void handleConfiguratorException(File file, AsyncSecret[] values, Exception e) {
        logger.error("Failed to retrieve the secrets from config server: " + e.getMessage());
        logger.error("Trying to Configure the secrets using backup");

        try {
            if (file.exists()) {
                properties = getProperties(path);
                if (properties != null && !properties.isEmpty()) {
                    HashMap<String, String> storedJSONValues = getStoredJSONValues();
                    updateConfiguratorWithBackupValues(storedJSONValues, values);
                    logger.info("Successfully configured the values to configurator from backup");
                } else {
                    logger.error("Failed to read from backup file as file is empty");
                }
            } else {
                logger.error("Old backup file does not exist in the location");
            }
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            logger.error("Exception occurred when reading JSON from backup: " + e1.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private static void updateConfiguratorWithBackupValues(HashMap<String, String> storedJSONValues,
            AsyncSecret[] values) {
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : storedJSONValues.entrySet()) {
            for (AsyncSecret val : values) {
                if (entry.getKey().equals(val.originalKey)) {
                    configurator.getAll().put(val.originalKey, entry.getValue());
                }
            }
        }
    }

        public static String processRequest(ServiceBase serviceBase)
        throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException, IOException {
    List<ServiceBase.Header> headers = new ArrayList<ServiceBase.Header>();
    headers.add(new Header("Accept", "application/json"));
    headers.add(new Header("Authorization", "Basic " + serviceBase.encodeCredentials()));
    String response = serviceBase.get(headers);
    log.info("Config server request processed");
    return response;
}

    private static HashMap<String, String> getStoredJSONValues() throws IOException {
        HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
        for (String key : properties.stringPropertyNames()) {
            hashMap.put(key, properties.getProperty(key));
        }
        return hashMap;
    }

    private static Properties getProperties(String path) throws IOException {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        try (InputStream resourceAsStream = new FileInputStream(path)) {
            properties.load(resourceAsStream);
        }
        return properties;
    }

    enum AsyncSecret {

        ASYNC_REALTIME_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD("restservice.ssl.keyPassword",
                "vault.async.realtime.ks.password.async.realtime.ks.password"),
        ASYNC_REALTIME_TRUSTORE_PASSWORD("restservice.ssl.trustStorePassword",
                "vault.async.realtime.ts.password.async.realtime.ts.password"),
        ASYNC_REALTIME_JWT_KEYSTOREPWD("jwt.keystorepwd", "vault.async.jwt.keystorepwd.async.jwt.keystorepwd");

        String originalKey;
        String vaultKey;

        AsyncSecret(String originalKey, String vaultKey) {
            this.originalKey = originalKey;
            this.vaultKey = vaultKey;
        }
    }
}









    package com.scb.infoatwork.util;
    
    import java.util.Arrays;
    
    import org.junit.Before;
    import org.junit.Test;
    import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
    import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
    import org.mockito.Mock;
    import org.mockito.Mockito;
    import org.mockito.invocation.InvocationOnMock;
    import org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner;
    import org.mockito.stubbing.Answer;
    
    import com.scb.xfw.config.Configurator;
    
    
    @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
    public class JsonUtilTest {
    
        @InjectMocks
        JsonUtil jsonUtil;
    
        @Mock
        Configurator configurator;
        
        @Before
        public void init()
        {
            this.configurator = Mockito.mock(Configurator.class);
            //Mockito.when(configurator.get("config.server.backup.basepath")).thenReturn(Mockito.anyString());
        }
        
        @Test
        public void instanceTest() throws Exception {
            JsonUtil jsonUtilMock = Mockito.mock(JsonUtil.class);
    //      Mockito.doAnswer(new Answer<Void>() {
    //          public Void answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) {
    //            Object[] args = invocation.getArguments();
    //            System.out.println("called with arguments: " + Arrays.toString(args));
    //            return null;
    //          }
    //      }).when(jsonUtilMock).getInstance(Mockito.anyString());
            Mockito.doNothing().when(jsonUtilMock).getInstance(Mockito.anyString());
        }
    
    }


package com.scb.infoatwork.util;

import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpException;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.GetMethod;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.PostMethod;
import org.apache.commons.*;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.*;

import com.scb.infoatwork.model.RestEndPoint;
import com.scb.xfw.logger.Logger;
import com.scb.xfw.logger.LoggerFactory;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.security.KeyManagementException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import java.util.Base64;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;

public class ServiceBase {

    private final RestEndPoint restEndPoint;

    HttpClient httpClient;
    
    static final String tlsversion= com.scb.xfw.config.Configurator.getInstance().get("realtime.tls.version");
    
    static transient final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getInstance()
            .getLogger(ServiceBase.class);  
    
    public ServiceBase(RestEndPoint restEndPoint) throws KeyManagementException, NoSuchAlgorithmException{
        this.restEndPoint = restEndPoint;
        this.httpClient = new HttpClient();
        enableSSL();
    }
   

    private SSLContext enableSSL() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException {
        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance(tlsversion);
        TrustManager[] trustManagers = {new ServiceBase.CustomX509SSL()};
        sslContext.init(null, trustManagers, null);
        ProtocolSocketFactory factory = new SecureProtocolSocketFactory() {
            public java.net.Socket createSocket(String host, int port)
                    throws java.io.IOException {
                return sslContext.getSocketFactory().createSocket(host, port);
            }

            public java.net.Socket createSocket(java.net.Socket socket, String host, int port, boolean autoClose)
                    throws java.io.IOException {
                return sslContext.getSocketFactory().createSocket(socket, host, port, autoClose);
            }

            @Override
            public Socket createSocket(String host, int port, InetAddress clientHost, int clientPort)
                    throws IOException, UnknownHostException {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return null;
            }
        };
        Protocol protocol = new Protocol("https", factory, 443);
        Protocol.registerProtocol("https", protocol);
        logger.info("SSL enabled to communicate with config server");
        return sslContext;
    }
 

    public String encodeCredentials(){
        String credentials = restEndPoint.getUserName() + ":" + restEndPoint.getPValue();
        byte[] encodeCredentials = credentials.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(encodeCredentials);
    }

    public URI createRequestURI(){
        return URI.create(restEndPoint.getBaseUrl()
                + "/" + restEndPoint.getApplicationName() + "/" + restEndPoint.getEnvironment()).normalize();
    }

    static class CustomX509SSL implements X509TrustManager {
        @Override
        public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {

        }

        @Override
        public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
        }

        @Override
        public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
            return new X509Certificate[0];
        }

    }
    
    public String get(List<Header> headers) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException, HttpException, IOException{
            
        GetMethod getMethod = new GetMethod(createRequestURI().toString());

        logger.info("Adding the request headers");
        
        for(Header header:headers) {
            
            logger.info(header.getHeaderName()+" = " + header.getHeaderValue());
            
            getMethod.addRequestHeader(header.getHeaderName(), header.getHeaderValue());
        
        }
        
        int executeMethod = httpClient.executeMethod(getMethod);
        
        logger.info("The request has been processed");
        
        if(executeMethod == 200) {
            
            String responseBodyAsString = getMethod.getResponseBodyAsString();
            
            logger.info("Received the response from the config server:"+responseBodyAsString);
            
            return responseBodyAsString;
            
        }
        
        getMethod.releaseConnection();
        
        logger.info("Received the response from config server:"+getMethod.getResponseBodyAsString());
        
        return null;
        
    }

    
    public String post(List<Header> headers,String requestBody) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException, HttpException, IOException{
                
        PostMethod postMethod = new PostMethod(createRequestURI().toString());
   
        for(Header header:headers) {
            
            postMethod.addRequestHeader(header.getHeaderName(), header.getHeaderValue());
        
        }
        
        postMethod.setRequestBody(requestBody);
        
        int executeMethod = httpClient.executeMethod(postMethod);
    
        if(executeMethod == 200) {
            
            String responseBodyAsString = postMethod.getResponseBodyAsString();
    
            logger.info("Received the response from config server:"+postMethod.getResponseBodyAsString());
            
            return responseBodyAsString;
            
        }
        
        postMethod.releaseConnection();
        
        logger.info("Received the response from config server:"+postMethod.getResponseBodyAsString());
        
        return null;
    
    }
    public static class Header{
        
        private String headerName;
        
        private String headerValue;
        
        public Header(String headerName, String headerValue) {
            this.headerName = headerName;
            this.headerValue = headerValue;
        }
        
        public String getHeaderValue() {
            return headerValue;
        }
        public String getHeaderName() {
            return headerName;
        }
        
        
    }

}
```

Comment: It would be great if you provide a reproducible code. However, you can read about mockito-inline, which helps to mock static methods. Also your @before useless, mock annotation is enough